# python showing import error while import openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

while using python openpyxl , it is showing error  , while openpyxl is updated .

```
[root@localhost callflowv2]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpyxl as op
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 396
    return f"{get_column_letter(min_col)}{min_row}:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"
```

Comment: How did you install `openpyxl`? And do you have a reason to use such an old version of Python? This code uses Python 3.6+ f-strings, but you're using Python 2.7.

Comment: (Note that Python 2.7 has been end-of-life for nearly 2.5 years. If you're working on new code I urge you to use a more recent version.)

Comment: @Chris : agree with you , but in production environment for legacy system ,there is no internet , where only python2.7 is there  , even if you see in current rhel 8 or Centos 8 by default python 2.7 is available .For installing python3 ,need to install separately .

Answer (score 0):

Actually latest version openpyxl not working well for load_workbook for python2.7 version .
so just uninstall openpyxl by command --> pip uninstall openpyxl .

then reinstall openpyxl by giving providing version of same like for me

pip install openpyxl=2.5.3 works